# What is the best way of writing the number of occurrences of a word in a file for multiple files and writing the results to another file

Tags: python, linux

This is simply for hopes of improving my programming skills.  The script works for what I am trying to do, I'd just like to know if there's a better or more favored way of doing it.  After 2 days, if the only response I have is "this is how it should be done", I'll accept that as the best answer.  I doubt it though.  This was also the first time writing a script in Linux, so that was fun.

We have a bunch of log files that are saved in different sub directories of a primary directory.  We wanted to write a script that would look through all of the log files for the words 'Error' and/or 'Exception', and increment a counter per file.  It would write all the results into 1 Error file and 1 Exception file.  So, the end files should have something like:

```
Errors:
dir/subdir1/log1.log: 23
dir/subdir2/log2.log: 2
dir/subdir2/log3.log: 194
dir/subdir3/log4.log: 1
```

Same goes for exceptions. This essentially let's us know where most of the failures are occurring.  Here is the code that I wrote to accomplish this:

```
# set today's date and the directory that will be searched through recursively (1)
date - datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
dir = "directory/of/main/folder"

# set file names containing today's date (2)
errors_file = "%s/%s_LogErrors.txt" % (dir, date)
exceptions_file = "%s/%s_LogExceptions.txt" % (dir, date)

# create 2 text files containing the name of each log file matched with the corresponding number of errors or exceptions (3)
os.system("cat * | grep -r -i -c 'Error' '%s' > '%s'" % (dir, errors_file))
os.system("cat * | grep -r -i -c 'Exception' '%s' > '%s'" % (dir, exceptions_file))

# open the errors file and set the contents of the file to error_content (4)
error_file = open(os.path.join(dir, errors_file), 'r')
error_content = error_file.readlines()
error_file.close()

# write a header to the errors file (5)
error_file = open(errors_file, 'w')
error_file.write("-"*120 + "\n")
error_file.write("These are the errors from all the log files.  The number on the right is the number of "
             "errors in the corresponding file.\n")
error_file.write("-"*120 + "\n")

# remove lines that have 0 errors and add a space between the colon and the number of errors (6)
for line in error_content:
    if line.strip().endswith(":0"):
        continue
    else:
        error_file.write(line.replace(":", ": ") + "\n")
error_file.close()

# open the exceptions file and set the contents of the file to exception_content (7)
exception_file = open(exceptions_file, 'r')
exception_content = exception_file.readlines()
exception_file.close()

# write a header to the exceptions file (8)
exception_file = open(exceptions_file, 'w')
exception_file.write("-"*128 + "\n")
exception_file.write("These are the exceptions from all the log files.  The number on the right is the number "
                 "of exceptions in the corresponding file.\n")
exception_file.write("-"*128 + "\n")

# remove lines that have 0 exceptions and add a space between the colon and the number of exceptions (9)
for line in exception_content:
    if line.strip().endswith(":0"):
        continue
    else:
        exception_file.write(line.replace(":", ": ") + "\n")
exception_file.close()
```

I added a number to the comment of each chunk to make it easier for you guys to reference a particular section of code.  It just seems like I wrote more code than needed, but I don't know what would be changed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did very good on your first attempt :).
What you should consider is to write your code less obfuscating.
For example, you do something like this:

```
os.system("cat * | grep -r -i -c 'Error' '%s' > '%s'" % (dir, errors_file))
```

First off all, using os.system for things like this is more the bash way. Mostly bash leaves the work to other programs where python likes to do it himselve. So, with python you should consider walking through the filenames using glob, or os.walk, or something and opening the file one by one, reading them line by line and counting for words (maybe using the re module). You can do this all with python modules and python language. Because you write out your whole code it is easier to understand than this grep command, which basically does all the work, but is not very descriptive. Furthermore you can do litterally everything in one loop (also the clearing out empty lines and stuff).

Another point I'd like to make is that you do 'cat * | grep', but in the end cat helps nothing, since your grep command is the one reading all the files and counting lines. Basically cat only eats a little performance and adds nothing to the table.

One other point is that you should better use the subprocess module than the os.system call. You can read about here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system